# Custom delimiter while exporting hive table to CSV from shell command line?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, export-to-csv, hiveql

I use the following command and the file I get in CSV is tab delimited.

```
hive -e "select * from my_table_name" > my_csv_file_received_daily.csv
```

And I have to reformat the files everytime. Is there a simple way to change this commance to get a comma delimited file instead of tab.

Answer (score 1):

```
insert overwrite local directory 'my_csv_file_received_daily'
row format delimited 
fields terminated by ',' 
select * from my_table_name
;
```